# How to pass optional arguments via = correctly in the presence of positional arguments in argparse?

Tags: python, argparse

I'm trying to migrate an old command-line parser to argparse-module. The old parser has some quirks one of which is, that the options are passed via `=`, i.e.

```
--foo=bar
```

which also works quite well with argparse. Yet there is one type of options I'm not able to map onto argparse-functionality:

- if used as `--foo`, the option `foo` gets a default value (let's call it `bar`)
- if used as `--foo=baz`, the option `foo` gets value `baz`.

At first, it look as if

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--foo', nargs='?', const='bar', type=str)
....
```

would do the job, but the problems arise when there are also positional arguments, e.g.:

```
....
parser.add_argument('pos', nargs='+')
```

Now, the following input fails with `argparse`, but works with the "legacy" parser:

```
parser.parse_args(['--foo', 'p1'])
```

because the parser assumes that `p1` belongs to `foo` and doesn't consider it to be a positional argument which should belong to `pos`.

Is there a way to tweak the parser, so that also the above case is parsed the same way it were done by the legacy parser, i.e. `foo=bar` and `pos=pos1`?

---

There are some test examples, which should work with the argparse-solution (only the last fails with current version):

```
Input:                          Expected Output:
-----------------               ----------------
['p1', '--foo']                 foo=bar, pos=p1
['p1', '--foo=baz']             foo=baz, pos=p1
['p1', '--foo', 'baz']          foo=baz, pos=p1
['--foo=baz', 'p1']             foo=baz, pos=p1
['--foo', 'baz', 'p1']          foo=baz, pos=p1
['p1']                          foo=None, pos=p1
['--foo']                       error (p1 not provided)
['--foo', 'p1']                 foo=bar, pos=p1   (fails with current version)
```

Comment: have you tried `parser.parse_args(['p1', '--foo'])`, it seems to me that 'positional' arguments should be positioned before any optional arguments?

Comment: @fgoudra usualy, the positionals come after optional, one can see it in the usage-message: "usage: xxx [-h] [--foo [FOO]] pos [pos ...]". However, because the old parser accepted them eitherway I need to do the same in order not to introduce a breaking change.

Comment: What's the legacy parser?  `optparse`?  If so I'd stick with that, since it's not going away (deprecation warnings or not).

Comment: @hpaulj,  no it is not optparse, but a "handmade" command line parser.  The project has different command line interfaces, which for historical reasons use different parsing-frameworks and the goal is to use only one framework.

Comment: The key to `argparse` here is that the `nargs='?'` gets the next string whether it is linked with '=' or not.  It is greedy, and does not take into account the needs of the following positional.  There isn't a 'global' argument allocation mechanism.

Comment: Just to clarify the '?' behavior.  If '--foo' is missing, 'foo=default'.  If '--foo' present without following argument, 'foo=const'.  Otherwise it is 'foo=value'.  It's a handy 3 way option.  But there's no mechanism to say, reserve the following string for the positional. It is causes confusion, use the simpler default `nargs`, which omits the `const` case.

Comment: @hpaulj that means, `?` should be used only if there are no positional arguments, because otherwise there always could be confusion? Not using `?` would mean a change of behavior, which we would like to avoid.